# How to segregate an monthly data from daily data using sql or bigquery?

Tags: sql, machine-learning, google-bigquery, data-analysis

We are receiving data monthly for some ids and daily for some ids. I need to segregate the data as monthly or daily before applying the logic required for further analysis.
i have tried to use datadiff sql function to do that, but its not really helpful in this case. Is there any way to segregate the daily receiving data from monthly using sql or big query?

```html
Id  date
55  11-02-2022 00:00
66  15-05-2022 00:00
77  13-08-2022 00:00
66  15-07-2022 00:00
77  12-08-2022 00:00
55  12-02-2022 00:00
66  15-06-2022 00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

A count aggregation per id per month is an efficient way to separate the two groups. The question is whether a single ID consistently updates at the same cadence, and if it does not, do you want to treat it differently per time period or always daily if ever daily, etc.

Here's the basic logic to categorize the two groups by month

```
select
    id
    , date_trunc(date, MONTH) as mo
    , count(*) > 1 as is_daily
from tbl
group by 1,2;
```

That gives you a per-id, per-month categorization.

Here is the same logic taken a step further to categorize any ID that ever receives daily updates as daily.

```
with bins as (
    select
        id
        , date_trunc(date, MONTH) as mo
        , count(*) > 1 as is_daily
    from tbl
    group by 1,2
)
select
    id
    , sum(case when is_daily then 1 else 0 end) > 0 as is_daily
from bins
group by 1;
```